# How to know which version of DMR (Device Media Renderer) to choose?

Tags: upnp, dlna

I want to implement a DLNA Device Media Renderer (DMR) for audio streaming. I found documentation here: http://upnp.org/resources/upnpresources.zip  and found out that there seems to be three versions of DMR's (MediaRenderer:1, MediaRenderer:2, MediaRenderer:3). I can't find any advice on which one to choose. Is there any reason not to choose MediaRenderer:3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to UPnP services are guaranteed to be backwards compatible so every MediaRenderer:3 device will contain an implementation of v1 and v2 services and will respond to a MSEARCH for v1 or v2 as that version.

See the v1.1 Device Architecture doc (included in the zip you reference) for more details, specifically

§1.2.2 Device available - NOTIFY with ssdp:alive

> Updated UPnP device
>   and service types are REQUIRED to be fully backward compatible with
>   previous versions of the same type.

§1.3.2 Search request with M-SEARCH

> Updated versions of device and service types are REQUIRED to be fully
>   backward compatible with previous versions. Devices MUST respond to
>   M-SEARCH requests for any supported version. For example, if a device
>   implements “urn:schemas-upnporg: service:xyz:2”, it MUST respond to
>   search requests for both that type and
>   “urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:xyz:1”. The response MUST specify the
>   same version as was contained in the search request

In other words, a device that correctly implements MediaRenderer:3 will be usable by control points which expects v1, v2 or v3 services.  A device which implements an earlier version of the services would be limited to working with control points which expect these earlier versions.

I agree with you that implementing MediaRenderer:3 is your best bet.  This should allow your device to be used by all possible control points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not sure that I understood. So the reason to choose MediaRenderer:1 over MediaRenderer:3 is just if I know that i will be using it together with other v1 services/devices? If I don't know what services I will work with (v1, v2 or v3) then I should probably choose MediaRenderer:3 because it can work with all devices? Did you get this information from reading the descriptions about the different media renderers or do you know any other good source where I can find this information?

Comment: Re-reading it, my answer was rather muddled (and the conclusions were wrong).  I've edited it now to say that I agree with your assessment that implementing MediaRenderer:3 is best for you.  Info on backwards compatibility comes from reading the device architecture docs and implementing a UPnP stack.  I'll add a specific reference for this into my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that answer. I can't say that everything is crystal clear and I will probably ask some more questions but I guess those questions will be posted under another topic when I have read a bit more of those specifications.